# Multiple Line chart with 2 dataSets

Tags: ios, swift, charts, linechart, ios-charts

I am trying to draw Multiple line chart using iOS-Charts danielgindi/Charts library by  as show in picture.

***Expected Output:***
[image]

```
Data1 = [Jun: 34, Jul: 42, Aug: 32, Sep: 30, Oct: 38]

Data2 = [Oct: 38, Nov: 40, Dec: 32, Jan: 40]

let dataSet1 = LineChartDataSet(values: Data1, label: nil)
dataSet1.lineDashLengths =[0]
dataSet1.drawCirclesEnabled = false

let dataSet2 = LineChartDataSet(values: Data2, label: nil)
dataSet2.lineDashLengths =[10]
dataSet2.drawCirclesEnabled = true

let data = LineChartData(dataSets:[dataSet1, dataSet2])
lineChartView?.data = data
```

I want to draw the first set with **solid line** and second set with **Dotted line**.

I am using iOS Charts library. (MultiLineChartView)
The problem which I m facing is the dotted line also start at the beginning of x-Axis. (As shown below)

[image]

Could anyone help me on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be having minimum and maximum for the x-Axis so you just have to set the starting x-axis for your second set to be the ending x-axis of the first data set. A very good example is included in the examples as `CombinedChartViewController`. Please try to run the demo and play with the x-Axis of any type of chart,

```
ChartDataEntry(x: 0.5, y: 30)
```